# IE8 Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting this error message only in IE8, and I don't know how to convert the existing function for IE8 compatibility.

> ```
> _initEvents : function() {
>      var self = this;
>
>      Array.prototype.slice.call(this.menuItems).forEach(function(el, i) {
>          var trigger = el.querySelector('a');
>
>          if (self.touch) {
>              trigger.addEventListener('touchstart', function(ev) {
>                    self._openMenu(this, ev); 
>                });
>          }
>          else {
>              trigger.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
>                    self._openMenu(this, ev);
>                });  
>         }
>      });
>    window.addEventListener('resize', function(ev) {
>          self._resizeHandler();
>      });
>
> },
> ```

the above is just a part of it, I dont think the rest is needed. The error happens here:

> ```
>  Array.prototype.slice.call( this.menuItems )
> ```

Comment: `forEach` is not supported in IE8.

Comment: @elclanrs—I may be wrong, but I suspect it doesn't get that far. The error is consistent with *menuItems* being a DOM object, not a native object. Host objects can't be treated like native objects in IE.

Comment: What is *menuItems*? Is it a DOM object?

Comment: @RobG: I immediately thought the same.  If it's a NodeList, for instance, `slice()` won't convert it to an array in IE <= 8.

Comment: There's no reason to do the slice. Since you seem to have `.forEach()` shimmed, you can just do `Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.menuItems, func...)`. This will avoid the IE8 issue of setting the `this` value of a native method to a non-native object.

Comment: What happens if you call it `Array.prototype.slice.call(self.menuItems)` ?

Comment: @Crazy TrainYour method does not work. Now I'm getting: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @YuriyGalanter—that doesn't solve the "calling native method with host *this*" issue.

Comment: Here is the full piece of code. Line 80 is the problem http://pastebin.com/S4hdgZL3

Comment: @Mike—so there you go. [*querySelectorAll*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) returns a NodeList, which is a host object. Add a shim for *forEach* for IE and use CrazyTrain's suggestion.

Comment: If you _do_ want to use Array.prototype.slice to work with DOM elements (though I agree it's not needed here), I've added a shim at https://gist.github.com/brettz9/6093105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call:

```
this.menuItems = this.el.querySelectorAll( '.cbp-hsmenu > li' );
```

the object assigned to *menuItems* is a static [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which is a host object. Then when you do:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( this.menuItems )
```

you are calling a built–in method with a host object as *this*. In IE 8 and lower (and probably lots of other older browsers), you can't do that (there is no specification that says you should, though modern browsers let you).

The simple solution is to convert *menuItems* to an array using some other method than *call*, or to [add a shim for *Array.prototype.forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use CrazyTrain's suggestion:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.menuItems, func...)
```

because in browsers without a built–in *forEach*, it will be a native method and work just fine. But for robust code, replace all that with a simple for loop.

Comment: "there is no specification that says you should" --- doesn't specification state `.call()`'s behaviour? http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code. This is not something I have created and my js knowledge is very limited. Thanks

Comment: If OP doesn't have `.forEach()` patched, then what are the odds that `.addEventListener()` is patched?

Comment: @Mike: As soon as you figure out the patch for `.forEach()`, you're going to realize that `.addEventListener()` won't work. I'm guessing you're using someone's code that was written for modern browsers. To make IE8 work you may want to consider loading a [DOM-shim library](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM).

Comment: @zerkms—[ECMA-262 Section 4, first paragraph](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4): "…but also certain environment-specific host objects, whose description and behaviour are beyond the scope of this specification". The issue isn't with the built-in method but with the host object.